Why does `od` introduce leading zeros?
Using Solaris 10 ipsec  the key must be converted in hex format. So I need a command to convert text in hex.
This line works fine
echo "mypassword" | od -t x1|head -1|tr -d ' ' |tr [a-z] [A-Z]

Produce
00000006D7970617373776F72640A

Anyway using an online converter it return this
6D7970617373776F72640A

As a workaround I use this
echo "mypassword" | od -t x1|head -1|tr -d ' ' |cut -c 8-1000|tr [a-z] [A-Z]

it return
6D7970617373776F72640A

The question is..why od return those 00000000?

tr does not use bracketed range notation, and should in general be quoted to avoid shell expansions and globbing. Like: tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'. It is simplest to test pipelines by appending one additional command at a time.

0000000 is an offset that is inserted at the beginning of each new line. The offset can be altered using an option, according to the manpage, -A, --address-radix: output format for file offsets; RADIX is one of [doxn], for Decimal, Octal, Hex or None.
You would like to omit the offset, so put -An in your script.

Note that the --address-radix long option is specific to the GNU implementation of od, Solaris' one doesn't have it. The OP will likely want to use the -v option as well.
